# PHP mySQL database update values not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I want to update values in my database.

Here is the part where i add the button that adds points to your account in **index.php** code:

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="grid points-grid">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="cell-content section-content"><div class="points-add">
                <div class="banner-wrap">
                    <a href="#" type="submit" class="btn" name="addpoints">Add 10 points</a>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is the part where i add the buttons function and adds the points in **functions.php**:

```
if (isset($_POST['addpoints'])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points += '10' WHERE 1");
}
```

I tried to find an solution and i didn't found a working one.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Is there some Javascript going on that you haven't posted? An `<a href="#">` won't actually send anything to the server.

Comment: Why would you want to update **all** rows in that table? Also: `+=` is an invalid operator in SQL (and MySQL). And finally: `'10'` is a string, not a number in SQL. `10` is a number

Comment: There is no javascript.

Comment: You can use js ajax .

Comment: Weird how nobody mentioned that OP is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@marakusa i don't know what you trying to accomplish with this code that you show to us, but if i understand something, is that you want to update users points in the database, i will show you how i would go about it in a simple way.

first i don't know why you would want to use an a tag if you don't have an attention to use javascript (ajax). so i changed it to a regular HTML form just like @bistrovs suggested

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="grid points-grid">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="cell-content section-content">
              <div class="points-add">
                  <div class="banner-wrap">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addpoints">
                        Add 10 points
                      </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

then in a functions.php file that i include in the same page where the form is, i update the user points by running this sql query :

```
if(isset($_POST['addpoints']) {

    $query = "UPDATE users SET points = points + 10 WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

i hope this could be useful for you

---

### Updated

**database structure**

```
-- Base de données :  `demo`

-- Structure de la table `users`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- Contenu de la table `users`

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `points`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Doe', 'john@doe.com', 0),
(2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'jane@doe.com', 0);
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 

include 'functions.php';

if(isset($_POST['addpoints'])) {

    $query = "UPDATE users SET points = points + 10 WHERE id = 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if ($result) {

        echo "user points updated";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<div class="content">
    <ul class="grid points-grid">
        <li class="item">
            <div class="cell-content section-content">
              <div class="points-add">
                  <div class="banner-wrap">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="addpoints">
                        Add 10 points
                      </button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I got this error Notice: Undefined variable: id in /storage/ssd5/427/3036427/public_html/functions.php on line 29. And this Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /storage/ssd5/427/3036427/public_html/functions.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd5/427/3036427/public_html/index.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/427/3036427/public_html/functions.php on line 30. Those are in if(isset($_POST['addpoints'])) {
     $query="UPDATE users SET points= points + 400 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }

Comment: **Undefined variable: id** it means your trying to use an undefined variable, it has to be defined some where in your php script, this is supposed to be the user id that you are trying to update his points. i don't know if i could be more clear than that.

for **Call to undefined function mysql_query()** i think your php version is >= 5.5.0, because mysql_query() function, and i quote from php documentation _"This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0"_ for more info check [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: My web servers PHP version is 7.0.8. And phpMyAdmins is 4.6.6. Can you make solution for 7.0.8?

Answer (score 1):

Does your page produce any errors?

I would suggest not using `<a>` tag to submit, Better solution:

```
<form >
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="addpoints">
</form>
```

I believe there is a problem in your SQL's Where statement:
`WHERE 1`
You do not specify a column. It should be something like `points = points+10 Where userID=1`